# draw a triangle within a triangle Tkz-Euclide

Tags: tkz-euclide

I want to produce an isosceles triangle within an isosceles triangle like below but being able to move the base AB by just changing the y-coordinate, I have tried different get point commands but no luck so far.

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}

%Diagram enviroment    
\newenvironment{diagram}
{\begin{center}\vspace*{10pt}\begin{tikzpicture}}
    {\end{tikzpicture}\vspace*{-5pt}\end{center}}

\begin{document}
\begin{diagram}
    \tkzDefPoint(-2,0){A}
    \tkzDefPoint(2,0){B}
    \tkzDefPoint(0,4){C}
    \tkzDefPoint(3,-2){D}
    \tkzDefPoint(-3,-2){E}

        \tkzDrawPolygon(A,B,C)
    
            \tkzDrawSegment(A,E)
            \tkzDrawSegment(B,D)
            
                \tkzLabelPoints[left](A)
                \tkzLabelPoints[right](B)
                \tkzLabelPoints[above](C)
                \tkzLabelPoints[left](E)
                \tkzLabelPoints[right](D)
        
                    \tkzMarkSegment[mark=|](A,C)
                    \tkzMarkSegment[mark=|](B,C)
            
                        \tkzMarkAngle[size=0.5](B,A,C)
                        \tkzMarkAngle[size=0.5](C,B,A)
\end{diagram}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Your question is not very clear.  You should explain what you are trying to obtain.  There are infinitely many isosceles triangles inscribed into a given isosceles triangle.  Which one are you looking for graphically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to give you the idea I post a solution suggestion for your exercise, not using the `y-coordinate` but using the command `\tkzDefPointOnLine` of `tkz-euclide` package, page 50 of latest version of user manual. You only need to change the `pos=x.y` parameter in **both**  and using the **same decimal number>1** in commands `\tkzDefPointOnLine` (you can also can use a defined variable for this) to get the new outer triangle. I used most of your code which can be shorter as you can see the first 3 lines I changed. I think you can add the angles, points etc. If this does not help please let me know what exactly you want to achieve.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,calc,shapes,patterns,decorations.pathmorphing,shadows.blur,shadings}

\begin{document}
    
\begin{tikzpicture}
  
        \tkzDefPoints{-2/0/A,2/0/B,0/4/C}
        \tkzDefPointOnLine[pos=1.5](C,A)\tkzGetPoint{E}
        \tkzDefPointOnLine[pos=1.5](C,B)\tkzGetPoint{D}
        \tkzDrawPolygon(A,B,C)
        \tkzDrawPolygon(D,E,C)
            \tkzDrawSegment(A,E)
        \tkzDrawSegment(B,D)
        
        \tkzLabelPoints[left](A)
        \tkzLabelPoints[right](B)
        \tkzLabelPoints[above](C)
        \tkzLabelPoints[left](E)
        \tkzLabelPoints[right](D)
        
        \tkzMarkSegment[mark=|](A,C)
        \tkzMarkSegment[mark=|](B,C)
        
        \tkzMarkAngle[size=0.5](B,A,C)
        \tkzMarkAngle[size=0.5](C,B,A)
        \tkzDrawSegment(E,D)
\end{tikzpicture}
    
\end{document}
```

Hope this will help you!

[image: output]

Comment: Perfect thank you so much

Answer (score 2):

This solution it will auto-adjust while changing the length of the base `AB` or the distance between the point `C` and the base:

```
\newcommand{\ABC}{-4} % distance between C and AB
\newcommand{\AB}{1} % base AB
```

[image: c]

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}

%Diagram enviroment    
\newenvironment{diagram}
{\begin{center}\vspace*{10pt}\begin{tikzpicture}}
        {\end{tikzpicture}\vspace*{-5pt}\end{center}}

\begin{document}

\newcommand{\ABC}{-4} % distance between C and AB
\newcommand{\AB}{1} % base AB

\begin{diagram}
\tkzDefPoint(0,0){C}    
\tkzDefShiftPoint[C](-\AB,\ABC){B}
\tkzDefShiftPoint[C](\AB,\ABC){A}   
\tkzDrawSegments(A,B B,C C,A)

\tkzDrawLines[add=0 and 0.5](C,A C,B)   
\tkzLabelLine[pos=1.5,right](C,A){D}    
\tkzLabelLine[pos=1.5,left](C,B){E}
    
\tkzLabelPoints[right](A)
\tkzLabelPoints[above](C)
\tkzLabelPoints[left](B)

\tkzMarkSegment[mark=|](A,C)
\tkzMarkSegment[mark=|](B,C)

\tkzMarkAngle[size=0.3](C,A,B)
\tkzMarkAngle[size=0.3](A,B,C)

\end{diagram}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I want to accept your answer as well but I can't, even though they get a similar answer.